# Aligning items in nav bar social icons wont center

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

Hello on my nav bar I have ran into a problem where I can't get my crisis help button to stay on the left and my social media icons to center. I have tried justify content, padding etc. The only place it works is when its under the header{} in the css file however then the button is centered to and I cant get that to go left.

````
```     <body>
       <header>
         <nav>
           <ul class="crisis_bar">
             <a class="crisisbutton" href="#">Crisis HELP!</a>
             <li><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
             <div class="social"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li>```
````

````
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Concert+One&display=swap');
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 3px 3%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;


}
.crisis_bar {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.crisis_bar li{
}

.crisis_bar li a {
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.crisisbutton {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  background-color: #f3755d;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #edf0f1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;
  left: 40%;
}
.crisis_bar .social{
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the "position: absolute;" above the "left:x%;" tag.
Hope it helped ^^

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I created two class called 'half' which I put the crisis bar in the first one, and the media icons in the second. I removed some code that wasn't necessary. I also noticed that you were missing the closing `</li>` tags.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Concert+One&display=swap');
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
header{
  padding: 3px 3%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

nav {
  width:100%;
}
.crisis_bar {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.crisis_bar li a {
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.crisisbutton {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  background-color: #f3755d;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: #edf0f1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;
}

  .half {
    width:50%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<header>
         <nav>
           <ul class="crisis_bar">
              <div class = "half">
             <a class="half crisisbutton" href="#">Crisis HELP!</a>
           </div>
             <li><i class="fa fa-facebook">facebook</i>/</li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-instagram">instagram</i></li>
             <li><i class="fa fa-twitter">twitter</i></li>
             <div class="half social"><li> <i class="fa fa-facebook">facebook</i></li></div>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            
</body>
```